# Initialize a Linked List nodes using map().reduce()

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, java-stream

I want to do this initialization of the Node class using java streams. How do I do this using the map and reduce stream operations?

```
Node node5 = new Node(5,null);
Node node4 = new Node(4,node5);
Node node3 = new Node(3,node4);
Node node2 = new Node(2,node3);
Node node1 = new Node(1,node2);
```

I've tried something like this, which does not compile

```
Node node = Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
    .map((i, n) -> new Node(i, n)
    .reduce(null, new SingleList.Node(i, n)));
```

I want to map each element in the array to `Node(int i , Node n)` and then reduce it to a `Node`. What am I missing here?

Comment: ...why...?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not sure this is going to be doable.  In particular, `reduce` doesn't guarantee how it orders the reduction of the elements.

Comment: This behavior isn't [*stateless.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness)

Comment: why - I want to initialize the objects dynamically using  array of inputs generated by a server and also want to keep the memory foot print low.

Comment: What is the result `node` supposed to be? The same as `node1` when you do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize a `List` of object `Node` with specific values of an array, and not from 0 to n, you could use the `iterate` operation to generate the indexes and traverse the array from the last element to the first one. Then, as you suggested, you could map every `int` to an `Integer` (or using the `boxed` operation) and then use the `reduce` operation to build your list starting from the bottom.

```
int[] vet = new int[]{7, 15, 6, 32, 44};
Node node = IntStream.iterate(vet.length - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> i)
        .reduce(null, (n, i) -> new Node(vet[i], n), (n1, n2) -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("No parallel execution supported");
        });
```

The previous code refers to a `Node` implementation like the following:

```
class Node {
    private int info;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int info, Node next) {
        this.info = info;
        this.next = next;
    }

    //... getters & setters ...
}
```

##### Output

```
Node temp = node;
while (temp != null) {
    System.out.println(temp.getInfo());
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on Dan ! that's exactly what I was looking for and it does the same this what this for  loop does :```Node head = new Node(0, null);
            for (int i = tailIndex-1; i >= headIndex; i--) {
                head = new Node(arrayValues[i], head);
        }```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a Linked List using Stream API and specifically `reduce()` operation.

But keep in mind that in essence it's a tricky way to mimic the `for` loop (*which will be a more suitable option*) and this stream can't be executed in parallel.

In order to create a stream containing the required number of elements, there's no need for generating an array and then use it as a stream-source. Instead, we can create a stream by using either [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)), which expects start and end `int` values (*it will work only if* `start < end`) or [`IntStream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)).

***Note*** that `box()` operation in required in order to transform the `IntStream` into a stream of objects in order to get access to this flavor of [`reduce(identity, accumulator, combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), wich allows to provide the identity of the type that differs from the type of the elements in the stream.

This form of `reduce()` is not available with `IntStream`.

The *tail node* should be provided as the *identity* of `reduce()` operation. The *accumulator* function is responsible for generating the *linked list* in reversed order (*from tail to head*). The node returned as a result of the execution of the stream pipeline would be the *head node*.

*Combiner* function, which is used to combine partial results produces in parallel, throws an `AssertionError` because if we would allow parallel execution each thread will instantiate its own identity (the *tail node*), which means that nodes would be linked incorrectly.

```
int tailValue = 5;
int headValue = 1;

// generating the linked list

Node head = IntStream.range(headValue, tailValue)
    .boxed()
    .reduce(new Node(tailValue, null),
            (Node node, Integer value) -> new Node(node.getValue() - 1, node),
            (Node left, Node right) -> {throw new AssertionError("should not be used in parallel");});

// printing the linked list

Node cur = head;
while (cur != null) {
    System.out.println(cur);
    cur = cur.getNext();
}
```

*Output:*

```
Node { value = 1 }
Node { value = 2 }
Node { value = 3 }
Node { value = 4 }
Node { value = 5 }
```

[*A link to the Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rmL)

> Tried something like this, which does not compile

```
Node node = Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
            .map((i, n) -> new Node(i, n))
            .reduce(null, new SingleList.Node(i, n)));
```

`Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})` will produce an `IntStream` (not a `Stream`).

Operation [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)), applied on the `IntStream`, expects an argument of type `IntUnaryOperator`, which is a function that takes a single argument of type `int` and returns `int` as well.

In order to transform the stream of primitives into a stream of objects, you should use `mapToObj()`, which expects an `IntFunction` (a function that takes a single `int` argument and returns an object).

The form of [`reduce(int identity, IntBinaryOperator combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce(int,java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator)), which is available with `IntStream` expects the *identity* of primitive type `int`, and its *combiner* is of type `IntBinaryOperator`, i.e. it takes `int` and produces `int`. Therefore, it would not compile.

There is also a logical flaw in your solution - you are attempting to create a *node* for each steam element twice: first time inside the `map()` and than during the `reduce()` operation, which is clearly redundant.

According to the documentation `map()` is a [*stateless operation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) it should not be "aware" of the previously encountered elements. Which means it can't be helpful in generating *nodes*, because it's unable to provide the reference to the *next node*.

---

A dummy `Node` class used above:

```
public static class Node {
    private int value;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int value, Node next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node {" +
            " value = " + value + " }";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, no need for streams. Just create an array of desired length, use the [Arrays.setAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method to fill the array and get the last element:

```
Node[] nodes = new Node[5];
Arrays.setAll(nodes, i -> new Node(nodes.length  - i , i == 0 ? null : nodes[i-1]));

Node node = nodes[nodes.length-1];
```

Comment: [Linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) data structure isn't backed by an array, it's comprised from a chain of *nodes* pointing to their neighbors. Implementations of the linked list only hold a reference to the *head node* (and in sometimes also to the *tail node*), but it doesn't maintain an array (Dynamic array does so, which implemented `ArrayList`, `Vector`, etc. in JDK). Only a single reference to the *head* is enough for a linked list to function.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I don't get what you are trying to say with your comment. I just copied your dummy `Node` class and my approach seems to produce the same result as yours.  Can you possibly explain the differences between my and your approaches? Or what, in your opinion, about my approach is not suitable for the question posed?

Comment: You've missed my point. OP implemented a custom Linked List (which is somewhat similar to the `LinkedList` from JDK). This data structure maintains a reference to the head node, it doesn't rely on the array (I hope that's clear). Your solution will generate all nodes as required, and will also allocate an array in memory. I've just pointed out that this array is redundant and will be then thrown away (only its last element is needed).